# Servlet.service() java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring-security

Can you tell me what this is? I did code refactoring and added some changes and got something like that

```
   @Configuration
public class SpringSecurity  {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public SpringSecurity(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void saveCostumer(){
        Customer customer = new Customer(1l, "test", "test", passwordEncoder().encode("test12311"), "test", "2345");
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> customerRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User email not found"));
    }

     @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws  Exception {
       return  authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
     }

     @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
         http
                 .authorizeRequests((auth) -> auth
                 .antMatchers("/api/auth/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/customer/test").permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 );

                 return http.build();
     }
```

Contoller

```
public class AuthController {


private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateCustomer(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto){

      Authentication authentication =  authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword()));

      Customer principal = (Customer) authentication.getPrincipal();

    System.out.println(principal.getUsername().toString());

      return null;
}
```

it causes this error, but email and password is correct

```
  Authentication authentication =  authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword()));
```

: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

Errror

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.getReferenceVolatile(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.getReferenceAcquire(Unsafe.java:2148) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.tabAt(ConcurrentHashMap.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:938) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:468) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:199) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: A `StackOverflowError` normally happens when you have a method that calls itself (directly or indirectly). Without seeing more of your code than just the one line you posted, it's not possible to tell exactly how / where this happens.

Comment: New issue! (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215) ..but what you do you s terrible: you overwrite spring's `/login` controller(don't!!)!

Comment: Overall, it started working today, although I didn't make any changes. ‍♂️ this" you overwrite spring's /login controller"  is only test form me